# Geometry nodes: Is there a way to create a point on each UV repetition tile?

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, vector-mapping

For example if I have a plane with an image texture on it and increase the size of the UV map to be bigger than the image.

Then the image will repeat a few times to cover the whole plane.
I would like to generate a point or sphere on each repeated tile. Is there a way to do this within geometry nodes?

Or alternatively a workaround maybe. I could generate a completely black image. Then add a white point in the center. Then maybe I can use geometry nodes to add a point at the location where it's white?